# Backup utilities that properly backup hardlinks

Tags: windows, backup

On Windows 8.1 for NTFS I wanna know what would be the best backup utility that properly backs up hard links (IE copies the links and doesn't create a duplicate file per link in the original drive but will copy the file location the links point to) and also supports incremental backups.

Hard links have huge advantages but right now if I backup a drive that uses them with my current backup tool, the backup uses up more space.

Thanks!

Comment: Not a programming question. Try [softwarerecs.se]

Comment: Should it run from Windows, or should it run from a "Live CD"? And, do you want to back up the whole drive or just some directories/files?

Comment: From Windows and I want to back up the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different Software for that. e.g. hardlinkbackup from Lupinhos

Or check the NTFS tools of Hermann Schinagl. specially ln with the delorean option http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/ln/ln.html

We have written our own tool (called ntfs-hardlink-backup) to run ln and do some magic like notification emails, log files, Shadow Volume copy etc. https://github.com/individual-it/ntfs-hardlink-backup
Its a command line tool and runs fine from a bat file or scheduled task.

Comment: I will check out hardlinkbackup when I return from work. By the way, does the other two tools you mentioned support incremental backups?

Comment: By the way it sounds like hardlinkbackup merely states it uses hardlinks as an optional means of backing up software, it doesn't say that it will properly backup hardlinks.

Comment: Decided to go with ln.exe, does an amazing job backing up hardlinks and is fast. Lacks a UI but I can live with that.

Comment: In the newest version of ln.exe there seems to be a bug when using delorian copy and making backups to a network share.
It can happen that changed files overwrite the history and deleted files are not deleted in the destination.
I've wrote to the developer and waiting for an answer.

Comment: I personally don't use the Delorean, I'm perfectly cool with Smart Mirror.